unbound[6165:0] fatal error: could not set up remote-control
This is a follow-up question to my 2nd question. The solution by @mpboden was implemented. In addition, I have added the auto-trust-anchor-file: and enabled remote-control:, as is defined in the Unbound example for Setting up for the rest of the network example.
server:
    directory: "/etc/unbound"
    username: "unbound"
    chroot: ""
    verbosity: 1
    logfile: "/etc/unbound/unbound.log"
    pidfile: "/etc/unbound/unbound.pid"
    # location of the trust anchor file that enables DNSSEC
    auto-trust-anchor-file: "/var/lib/unbound/root.key"
    # send minimal amount of information to upstream servers to enhance privacy
    qname-minimisation: yes
    # The port number on which the server responds to queries. 
    port: 3000
    # the interface that is used to connect to the network (this will listen to all interfaces)
    interface: 0.0.0.0
    interface: ::0
    # addresses from the IP range that are allowed to connect to the resolver
    access-control: 192.168.1.0/24 allow
    access-control: 2001:DB8::/64 allow

remote-control:
    # allows controling unbound using "unbound-control"
    control-enable: yes

However, I discovered 4 errors and 1 failure message using debug mode. From my troubleshooting efforts, I found that these error and failure messages occurred whenever control-enable: yes was allowed.
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# unbound -d -vv -c unbound.conf
[1730259092] unbound[6165:0] notice: Start of unbound 1.19.2.
[1730259092] unbound[6165:0] error: Error for server-cert-file: /etc/unbound/unbound_server.pem
[1730259092] unbound[6165:0] error: Error in SSL_CTX use_certificate_chain_file crypto error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory
[1730259092] unbound[6165:0] error: and additionally crypto error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib
[1730259092] unbound[6165:0] error: and additionally crypto error:0A080002:SSL routines::system lib
[1730259092] unbound[6165:0] fatal error: could not set up remote-control

I have checked that /var/lib/unbound/root.key exists. Unbound still works but unbound-control can't be used. Unbound is looking for /etc/unbound/unbound_server.pem but this file does not exist. How do I resolve this remote-control config issue?
Update:
with @mpboden answer, I discovered that the command unbound-control-setup is meant to create these files in /etc/unbound: unbound_control.pem,  unbound_server.pem, unbound_control.key, unbound_server.key, to allow remote control.
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# unbound-control-setup -h
usage: /usr/sbin/unbound-control-setup OPTIONS
OPTIONS
-d <dir>  used directory to store keys and certificates (default: /etc/unbound)
-h        show help notice
-r        recreate certificates
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# unbound-control-setup
setup in directory /etc/unbound
Certificate request self-signature ok
subject=CN = unbound-control
removing artifacts
Setup success. Certificates created. Enable in unbound.conf file to use
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# ls
unbound.conf    unbound.conf.d       unbound.pid          unbound_control.pem  unbound_server.pem
unbound.log     unbound_control.key  unbound_server.key


To enable unbound-control, you have to run the unbound-control-setup command that creates the necessary files.
Quoting from the official documentation on how to Set Up Remote Control:

To use the unbound-control command, we need to invoke the
unbound-control-setup command. This creates a number of files in the
default install directory. The default install directory is
/usr/local/etc/unbound/ on most systems, but some distributions may
put it in /etc/unbound/ or /var/lib/unbound.

Therefore, run the following command:
sudo -u unbound unbound-control-setup


If you use a username like unbound in the configuration to run the
daemon (which is the default setting), you can use sudo to create the
files in that user’s name, so that the user running Unbound is allowed
to read the keys. This is also a solution if the
/usr/local/etc/unbound/ directory (or any other default directory) is
write-protected, which is the case for some distributions


Thanks. As root, I ran unbound-control-setup and it set up the necessary files.

Can you advice me on another question on Unbound?
